# Prove $\sqrt{x^2-x+1}\ge\log{\left(\frac{e^x+e}{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

**The question:** Let $x\in \Bbb{R}$,  show that
$$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}\ge\log{\left(\dfrac{e^x+e}{2}\right)}$$

**My attempt:**
I have proven that 
$$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}(x+1)$$
since the right-hand side is the tangent line to $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$ at $x=1$.

So it suffices to prove
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(x+1)\ge \log{\left(\dfrac{e^x+e}{2}\right)},$$
but I haven't managed to do this.

Comment: The inequality at the end isn't true - note that $\log\left(\frac{e^x+e}{2}\right)\sim x$ for large $x$.

Comment: @πr8 yes, in fact its opposite is true by the convexity of $e^x$. So the linear approximation of the square root is too weak to be of any use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set $t=e^{x-1}$. Need to prove:
$$\sqrt{\mathrm{log}(t)(\mathrm{log}(t)+1)+1}\ge \mathrm{log}(\frac{et+e}{2})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(t)=\mathrm{log}^2(t)+\mathrm{log}(t)-\mathrm{log}^2(\frac{t+1}{2})-2\mathrm{log}(\frac{t+1}{2})\ge0$$
$$\Leftarrow f'(t)\ge0,t\ge1;f'(t)\le0,t\le1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow g(t)\ge0,t\ge1;g(t)\le0,t\le1$$
where $g(t)=(t+1)\mathrm{log}(t)-t\mathrm{log}(\frac{t+1}{2})-\frac{t-1}{2}, t\in(0,+\infty)$.

Now we would like to prove $g(t)$ to be increasing over $(0,+\infty)$.

$\displaystyle{g'(t)=\mathrm{log}(t)+\frac{t+1}{t}-\mathrm{log}(\frac{t+1}{2})-\frac{t}{t+1}-\frac{1}{2}\\
\qquad =\mathrm{log}(1+\frac{t-1}{t+1})+\frac{t+1}{t}-\frac{t}{t+1}-\frac{1}{2}\\
\qquad\ge\frac{t-1}{2t}+\frac{t+1}{t}-\frac{t}{t+1}-\frac{1}{2}\\
\qquad=\frac{3t+1}{2t(t+1)}>0}$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Well done. The first line: extra square in $\log$.

Comment: @A.G. thank you for that~

Comment: How do you show $\log\left(1+\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right) \ge \frac{t-1}{2t}$?

Comment: @angryavian hm, as $\log(1+x)\ge \frac{x}{x+1}$ when $x>-1$.

Comment: Very beautiful proof!